# Azure map drive system error 53 has occurred

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to map a storage account to a Virtual machine in Azure.

I am following a [simple tutorial](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/accessing-your-azure-files-from-inside-a-vm/) which details how to access your Azure Files from inside a VM.

You simply create a new storage account so that it has the new Azure Files access, then map a drive to the VM using net use:

```
net use z: \\tempstorage.file.core.windows.net\upload /u:tempstorage mykey
```

I am getting:

```
System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

I have made the container public and can access files located inside via the url:

```
https://tempstorage.blob.core.windows.net/upload/example.jpg
```

Any ideas why I am getting System error 53?

*Please note: the above urls are an examples and don't link to a read locations.*

Comment: I think you're getting confused between blob storage and file service. It seems you created a blob container in your"tempstorage" account but trying to mount as file service. What you would need to do is create a file service share called "upload" in file service and then mount that.

Comment: No, I am using the new Files Preview which allows you to access blob storage via a file share

Comment: No, I think that's where you're incorrect. Files Service and Blob Storage are two different services offered by Azure. You can't share blob containers via File Service. As I mentioned in my comment above, you would need to create a "Share" in your file service (which is like blob container) and then mount that in your VM. But you can't mount a blob container.

Comment: I see, they are completely different services.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850682/azure-files-system-error-53).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have first enabled that folder as a Share.  See step 3 on this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx

If you don't do this then you won't be able to map it to a virtual machine using the 'net use' command.

Comment: This seems like a possible answer, but the blog entry doesn't make it clear what step enables the folder as a share.   I'm using the Portal web page, and have created the file share.   I then clicked on the "Connect" button for the file share, which simply displays a message giving the `net use` command to use.   Issuing that command (with my storage key and drive letter) still gives the `System error 53 has occurred message`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this registry key to a value of 3

**HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa > *LmCompatibilityLevel***

For more information, see the [LmCompatibilityLevel](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc960646.aspx) topic on TechNet.

Got this solution from [this MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems)

Comment: Note that MS says this requires a reboot to take effect but in my testing it worked straight away.