# Azure Filesshare - System error 53 - Troubleshooting

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am also having the same problem as mentioned here [Azure Files - System error 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850682/azure-files-system-error-53)

Although I'm afraid the answers provided have not helped.

My current setup all in west europe

- File Share
- VM 1 Windows 2012 - Can connect to File Share
- VM 2 Windows 2012 - **Cannot** connect to File Share

I've run PortQRY which confirms that port 445 is outgoing and working.

Although I am still receiving this error
[image]

This error occurred after a random shutdown, before which I could connect fine.

What other troubleshooting steps can I take to find out why this is not working?

Comment: Have you followed this article [Azure Files Troubleshooting][1] ?

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-troubleshoot-file-connection-problems#error53

Comment: According to your description, it seems that no issue on your network between VM and Fileshare, you had better check `regedist`.

Comment: I ended up wiping the server and remaking it. I'm going to leave this question though encase others need any information from it.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Yes

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that no issue is on your network between VM and Azure FileShare.

You could refer to Mine's [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-troubleshoot-file-connection-problems#error-53-or-error-67-when-you-try-to-mount-or-unmount-an-azure-file-share), please check `Cause 3`.

> "System Error 53 or System error 87" can also be received if NTLMv1
>   communication is enabled on the client. Having NTLMv1 enabled creates
>   a less-secure client. Therefore, communication will be blocked for
>   Azure Files. To verify whether this is the cause of the error, verify
>   that the following registry subkey is set to a value of 3:+
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa > LmCompatibilityLevel.

I also met a similar question with you, you could check the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/227b79ed-4bcd-40f5-a695-8c20a4477437/system-error-53-has-occurred-network-path-not-found-mapping-to-azure-file-storage?forum=windowsazuredata). The solution is to modify the registry