# Cannot connect to Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-files

Created Azure file share in portal and copied the PowerShell script to connect it as drive Q: (verified not in use). Response:

```
New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct
At line:3 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name Q -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\xxxx.file.c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Q:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive],  Win32Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :      CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

where "xxxx" is the share name. The PS command was copied directly from the portal and not altered.

Comment: whas your Windows\powershell versions? You can find out with `$PSVersionTable`. I just tested and it works for me.

Comment: PSVersion=5.1.15063.786; BuildVersion 10.0.15063.786; CLRVersion 4.0.30319.42000

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows well its supported, i dont know, try copy\pasting in a fresh PS sessión. try rebooting?

Comment: Fiddler shows a 400 response, "The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server"

Comment: try verifying share name, try another pc? open support ticket?

Comment: Think I found it -- Comcast disallows port 445.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Files - System error 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850682/azure-files-system-error-53)

Comment: @BarryBriggs please provide your own answer and accept it. if you resolved your issue by own

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments above, Comcast blocks port 445. Solution was to have another object in the cloud reference the Azure File and then return the data to the client over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Several workaround for port 445 (SMB port) being blocked are listed here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-53-error-67-or-error-87-when-you-mount-or-unmount-an-azure-file-share

Comment: I would be helpful if the answer had more guidance. Something like you could follow "Solution 4 - Use REST API based tools like Storage Explorer/Powershell" and use the following powershell.code.example.