# Error connecting to Azure File Share from Windows 10 PC

Tags: azure-files

I am getting similar problem to that described here and other places:

[Cannot connect to Azure File Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233157/cannot-connect-to-azure-file-share)

but in my case it doesn't appear to be related to Port 445 being blocked.
Test-NetConnection with port 445 works OK, and returns an IP address.

Credentials are stored using CmdKey, but I cannot access the share in Window explorer using the UNC path, and New-PSDrive returns an error:

New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Needed to disable NTLMv1 by setting the registry key value to 3 for:

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa > LmCompatibilityLevel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems

Comment: The LmCompatibilityLevel key value doesn't exist on my Windows 10 machine.  Did you create this key value?

Comment: The setting was already there set to 1. I just had to change it to 3.